# Find the order of a function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the zero of this function.

$f(z)= \sin(z^2)$

i think the zero is $z=\sqrt{n\pi}$
but i am not sure with the order of zero. I derive 3 times. So I got third order.

Comment: What is a order of a function?

Comment: I have to derive the function and replace the zero, until the function be different to zero. all times that i derive means my zero order.

Comment: So you mean that the least $k$ such that $f^{(k)}(z) \neq 0$ is the order where $z$ is a zero?

Comment: yes my friend. exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

$$sin(z)=0 \iff z= n\pi \mathrm{\quad where\quad }n\in \mathbb Z.$$

So,

$$sin(z^2)=0 \iff z^2= n\pi,$$

i.e.,

$$z=\pm \sqrt{n\pi}\mathrm{\quad where\quad }n \geq0$$

and

$$z=\pm i\sqrt{-n\pi}\mathrm{\quad where\quad }n <0.$$

As for the order, the derivative of the function $sin\ z^2$ is $2zcos z$, which has order $1$ at each of the real zeros. So these are double zeros. The complex zeros are left as an exercise. I must after all leave out something, as this site is supposed to help you think for yourself.

Comment: if n=0 , replace in 2zcosz = 0, so i though is could not be of first order. 2(0*pi)(1)=0. is it Ok?

Comment: Think about it. Think for yourself.